# Is it possible to install regular, non go version of android firmware on a device running android go?

Tags: custom-roms, device-firmware, android-go

are there any alternative, 'non go' android firmwares for my Samsung J4 core phone available?

The Samsung J4 core comes with Android Go.

Comment: Maybe... This is entirely dependent on the device and if developers have come up with a custom ROM for it as each device is unique. Check XDA Developers forums for options is the best bet.

Comment: The Samsung J4 core has only 1 GB RAM, therefore a current regular Android version may cause trouble with such less RAM.